# Very slow loading while fetching WMS layer as image/svg ol5

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I want to fetch WMS layer as SVG image but it is loading very slow. How to resolve this issue?

Here is my code

```
var grid_10hact = new ol.layer.Image({
  title: '10 Hactare Grid',

    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({

        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms',

        params: {
            'LAYERS': 'soil_health:CG_STATE_GRIDE_10HA_WGS84',

            'VERSION': '1.1.1',
            'FORMAT': 'image/svg',

        }
    }),
    opacity: 0.6
});
```

Comment: how big or complex is your layer? an image format will nearly always be faster

Comment: i have 3 shapefiles and each shapefile is 38mb.

Comment: You my find a hint to solution here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/55241/convert-my-large-svg-image-into-tiles

Comment: I did not find any solution.geoserver and openlayer itself provide svg image facility but very slow rendering.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information. SVG is not an image format; if you measure the volume of data transferred, you might better understand why it takes a long time.